# How to add new btc block to blockchain

Tags: blockchain, mining-pools, development, mining-reward

Please let me known that "How I add a new BTC block to blockchain?" as a sole miner.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how you yourself can add a new block to Bitcoin's chain via solo mining, then unfortunately unless you have a lot of hardware to do so, you will likely never add a block yourself by solo mining.

And, if you had the hardware to do so, you wouldn't be asking this question.

If you're asking just in general, then chytrik's response is a good answer if you click the link.